# Merge multiple tables in a database

Tags: mysql, myisam, ubuntu

I have a MySQL database with table names like `1,2,3... upto 1000`

Each tables have `2000 rows` and has the same structure.

This is how all my 2000 table's structure look like

```
id,url,title,content
```

`id` has type int, primary key,auto increment.

Now I would like to create a new database with name `merged`. Also a table with name `merged_table`.

Can someone tell me how to import all my tables in `merged_table`?

My problem here is all my tables has `id` from `1 to 2000`. So I have no idea how to import them.

I would like to have unique ids from `1 to 2000000` in my new `merged_table`

I'm using ubuntu. So if someone suggest me a terminal command, that would be awesome.

Comment: Are all the tables MyISAM ???

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Yes

Comment: Is `merged_table` to be MyISAM also ???

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Yes

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA If innodb is best, then let's make it as innodb

Comment: One more question: Is the first MyISAM table really called `1` ???

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Yes..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the first table, then load each table into the merged_table:

```
CREATE TABLE merged_table LIKE `1`;
INSERT INTO merged_table (url,title,content) SELECT url,title,content FROM `1`;
INSERT INTO merged_table (url,title,content) SELECT url,title,content FROM `2`;
INSERT INTO merged_table (url,title,content) SELECT url,title,content FROM `3`;
...
...
;
INSERT INTO merged_table (url,title,content) SELECT url,title,content FROM `999`;
INSERT INTO merged_table (url,title,content) SELECT url,title,content FROM `1000`;
```

Here is a way to script it (if the database is mydb)

```
DB="mydb"
MYSQL_CONN="-uroot -ppassword"
echo "CREATE TABLE merged_table LIKE \`1\`;" > MergeData.sql
SQL="SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO merged_table (url,title,content)"
SQL="${SQL} SELECT url,title,content FROM \`998\`')"
SQL="${SQL} FROM information_schema.tables"
SQL="${SQL} WHERE table_name REGEXP "$[0-9]"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQL}" >> MergeData.sql
```

Look at the output of the file

```
less MergeData.sql
```

If it looks like the output I gave at the top of my answer, then run

```
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -D${DB} < MergeData.sql
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Great.. Thankyou.. I'll give it a try..

Comment: Excellent mate, It works perfectly. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I added a shell script to help generate it, if it will help.

Comment: Thanks for your shell script. I hope it will be useful for others. I've already used a php for loop to generate that table code you given.